# UIBarButtonItem setTitlePositionAdjustment on iOS 7 Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, position, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I have a `UINavigationBar` that has a new height of 85 and is fixed for landscape and portrait. I am adding an edit button at the top right corner but it wont stay there.

I've used the following:

```
[item setTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0, -47) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

But, if I rotate the device it moves back down 47 to the original location. If I change the metrics again it moves back to the original location. If I replace the button with another button it moves the new button to the original location, and setting the position for the new button does nothing.

I can't figure out how to move the button and get it to stay. There's no way to use constraints on the `UIBarButtonItem`.

Comment: I marked your question as a favorite and will check on it again in a few weeks. In my experience, setTitlePositionAdjustment:forBarMetrics: is broken when it comes to rotation in iOS 7.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to put a `UIView` in the top right corner as the `UINavigationBar` child. Make the `UIView` have the same height as the navigation bar, and put your button inside the view. You can then add constraints for the button inside the view.